# dump dictionary to sub element in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file of 'defaults' that looks something like this:

```json
{
   "locale": {
      "name": "Bobs Yuruncle",
      "city": "Boring",
      "state": "Maryland",
      "lang": "en-us"
   },
   "weather": {
      "temp": "° F",
      "wind": "mph"
   },
   "measurement": {
      "length_small": "inches",
      "length_medium": "feet",
      "length_long": "miles"
   },
   
   ...etc
}
```

I am building a class to be able to better abstract, access, and modify these default values, as well as create custom ones for custom functionality within my application.

Is there an easy way to use the `json` library to dump just one dictionary into a sub-element? For example, If I modified weather to

```json
{
   "temp": "° C",
   "wind": "kph"
}
```

is there an easy way to just override the `weather` sub-element within the file without having to read or mess with the rest of the file?

My current solution would be to just read all of it in, replace the sub-element, and then write it out, but I feel like there should be a better solution. Maybe I'm wrong, or maybe there's a library for that...

Comment: No, don't do that.  It's too error prone.  You can't update the middle of a text file.  JSON needs to be easy.  Just read the whole object, update your one part of the tree, and overwrite the file.

Comment: No, it's not possible to do that. You have to load the entire JSON into a Python variable, make the changes to that variable, then dump it back to the file.

Comment: I guess I'm too used to file-pointer dancing in C. Good to know.